# What is the advantage of a modal dialog vs a new page here

Tags: gui-design

I have a list view showing a datagrid of students for a selected class.

In order to manage the classes for those students I could show a dialog where the user can create/delete a class.

[image]

A minor problem that occurs here how to handle the deletion of the selected class or classes at all in the dropdown. over the list view.

Then I thought about just creating a new page "replacing" the list view and showing the Manage classes html page.

Now I think do I really need a modal dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modal is going to be a much better user experience if done correctly rather than taking the user away from their current page (you're breaking the flow).  Instead of making deleting an item difficult, make deleting an item easy.  Then make undoing the action just as easy.

A confirmation is only necessary when the following things are true:

- deleting the data is detrimental to the user
- recovering the data isn't possible

Think of it this way: when a user clicks delete, more than not, they're going to intend for the item to be deleted.  By having a confirmation, you're only adding additional work to the average user. Instead, by adding an undo option AFTER the delete operation has successfully went through, you're reducing user effort for the majority case, while still providing a safety net for users who accidentally delete an item. On top of this, you also have the added benefit that you no longer need to add a second modal.

Comment: There is no 2nd modal, its a popover control: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover&stacked=h What would you do when a class is deleted in the modal and the modal is closed? Reload the data so the class view checkbox is also only filled with the existing classes.?

Comment: I'd recommend placing the undo option on the main page, not in the modal.  Using your mock-up for example, I'd do something like change the X for close to an Undo button instead.  You'd have to mess with the icons and wording to see what fits best for your current design.

From there, I'd either keep the undo option visible until the user switches pages, or have it disappear if the user takes another action (at that point it's quite clear the user intended to delete whatever they did).

Comment: About: "(you're breaking the flow)" Is something modal not basically breaking a flow in general? You are forced to work a certain way. I agree with your undo option which I will implement later.

Comment: You're correct; the modal is breaking the flow slightly, but bringing the user to a completely different page is going to completely take them away from what they were doing, versus a modal is more of a temporary interruption.